# color coding of .phtml Zend framework files in Dreamweaver 8 win7

Tags: zend-framework, windows-7, dreamweaver, php

I am using Dreaweaver 8 in windows 7. Problem is that i cannot see color syntex coding  of phtml files.
How can i ???????
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a read here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html